# What are the distinctions and shared qualities between the Begotten Son of God and the rest of the children of God?

Tags: jesus, son-of-god, children-of-god

***Jesus on earth is different from his glorified status after his resurrection.  How is his progression to this same glory(John 17:5) distinct from, and similar to the proceeding children of God's progression to glory(John 17:22)?***

John 17:5

> And now, O Father, **glorify** thou me with thine own self with the **glory** which I had with thee before the world was.

John 17:22

> And the **glory which thou gavest me I have given them**; that they may be one, even as we are one:23 I in them, and thou in me, that they may be made perfect in one; and that the world may know that thou hast sent me, and hast loved them, as thou hast loved me.

**Premise**  This is to clarify who we are speaking about in verse 22.

John calls Jesus the begotten and tells us we can become sons(children) of God as well.

John 1

> 12 But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the **sons of God**, even to them that believe on his name:

> 13 Which were **born**, not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but **of God**.

> 14 And the logos was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the **only begotten** of the Father,) full of grace and truth.

Jesus called himself the (only) begotten son of God while he walked on the earth.

John 3

> 16 For God so loved the world, that he gave his **only begotten Son**, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
>
> 17 For God sent not his Son into the world to condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved.

> 18 He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the **only begotten Son of God**.

Jesus says many other things about the proceeding children of God.

Matthew 12

> 48 But he answered and said unto him that told him, Who is my mother? and who are my **brethren**?
>
> 49 And he stretched forth his hand toward his disciples, and said, Behold my mother and my **brethren**!

> 50 *For whosoever shall do the will of my Father which is in heaven, the same is my **brother, and sister, and mother**.*

Jesus is called the first of many, firstborn of the dead, firstborn of creation....

Paul calls him the firstfruits:

1 Corinthians 15

> 20 But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the **firstfruits** of them that slept.

> 21 For since by **man** came death, by **man** came also the resurrection of the dead.

> 22 For as in Adam all die, even so in Christ shall all be made alive.

> 23 But every man in his own order: Christ the **firstfruits**; afterward they that are Christ's at his coming.

Paul calls him the firstborn of many brethren.

Romans 8:29

> For whom he did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the **firstborn among many brethren.**

Colossians 1:18

> He is the head of the body, the church. He is the beginning, the **firstborn** from the dead, that in everything he might be preeminent.

Hebrews 1:6

> When he brings the **firstborn** into the world, he says, “Let all God’s angels worship him”.

Comment: This is a classic theological synthesis question (asking us to bring together the teachings of multiple passages) and so is off-topic on this site.

Comment: It's not uncommon for new users to take a while to get up to speed with the site scope, especially if you are not already familiar with [the field of hermeneutics and how that differs from "Bible Study"](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/13311). Please do adhere to the [Code of Conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct) and treat all users with respect, including Moderators. If you have concerns about Moderator behaviour please raise them to the Community Team using the Contact Form.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139911/discussion-on-question-by-read-less-pray-more-what-are-the-distinctions-and-shar).

Comment: My question to Jesse stands even though my comment was deleted.  What else do I need to do to open this question up besides finishing citing Paul? @Jesse

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי Repost: I know I'm new here... but this is first I've heard a questions closed because too much support was provided in the premise and a few verses from Paul need updated notes.... Can you further explain this phrase "multiple-passage cross-reference for a synthesis conclusion"?... And show me in the rules where this is somehow explained well enough for us to understand?

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי Repost: Also I'm not asking how Jesus is different than others. I asked how his progress to the glory is different from the progress to glory of the Children of God found in chapter 17 of John. So it seems you have closed my question on the basis of a strawman fallacy.

Comment: For all those who are downvoting to keep this question closed.... Can you provide suggestions to reopen?  Is this not an important topic to find an answer to?  Do not be afraid of discovering Truth about the children.  This is good news.

Comment: Exegesis questions on this site need to focus on one single passage. This is not an exegesis question - it is a theological synthesis question, asking for a whole theology of childrenhood-of-God to be explained.

Comment: @curiousdannii I 100% disagree.  Im very sorry but I am using one passage in the question:  the 17th chapter of John.  If you disagree and say a passage can't be as long a whole chapter.  Let me say... Jesus is speaking to his Father thee entire time.  The context is the same throughout.  The subdivisions added to the scripture are from babylon anyways.  Not from God.  The premise has many supportive verses as any good premise should.

Comment: Asking about a whole chapter is fine. The issue is this question appears to be highly dependent on John 1 & 3 as well as Matthew, Romans, 1 Corinthians, Colossians, and Hebrews. If you want to focus on John 17 then I suggest you remove all those other quotes and ask a clear exegetical question about John 17. If you need all those passages to support your premise, then it's probably not an exegetical question. Are you instead asking whether your premise can be supported by John 17?

Comment: @curiousdannii Actually I misspoke the verses in question are 7 verses apart.  John chapter 17 verse 5 and 22-23.  What is this glory our Master is speaking of?

Comment: No its not dependant.  I thought I'd get a lot of kickback for saying Jesus is the first of many children.  So I provided much support.  But why delete it?  You can never provide too much support in a rational explanation.

Comment: Do you want me to get rid of the premise so that the question changes to who is Jesus speaking of in John 17?  Because that is NOT the question I am interested in at all.

Comment: I think this is a case where the additional verses are obscuring the main question rather than adding clarity to it. Is your question focused on the glory of the Son and God's people in those verses? If so then none of the other quotes are necessary. I don't know why you'd think you'd get kickback for saying Jesus is the first of many children. That's accepted by Christians of all sorts. Our adoption by God is a major biblical theme!

Comment: My question is clear and the words I use are the words I use for a purpose.  Adoption or reborn?  Paul is not my master, therefore everything Paul says needs to be filtered through the lens of the words of Jesus Christ.

Comment: John 1:12-13 makes this clear.  That is why my premise needs to remain and I will continue to add to it if it needs to be added to.  But my question is of  a 9 verse passage of John 17.

Comment: Honestly this seems really cut and dry to me at this point.  This question is rational.  Its either rational or not. 
 Rationality should be the basis for questions and I will bring this up in Meta.

Comment: Adding rational premises to ALL questions is key to clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The Apostle John said at John 3:16 that Jesus Christ is  the "ONLY" begotten Son of God as in there are no others. The Bible speaks of Christians as sons of God BY ADOPTION.

Romans 8:15-17, "For you have not received a spirit of slavery leading to fear again but you have received a spirit of "ADOPTION" as sons by which we cry out "Abba! Father!" Vs16, The Spirit Himself bears witness with our spirit that we are children of God. Vs17, and if children, heirs also heirs of God and fellow heirs with Christ, if indeed we suffer with Him in order that we may also be glorified with Him."

The Holy Spirit bears unmistakable witness to our spirit that we are children of God. The new birth (John 3:3-6) gives spiritual life; the ADOPTION as sons guarantees privileges of sonship.

As C.S. Lewis puts it, "Christians are called adopted sons of God because we are different from God and must become His children (hence, adopted, not begotten). Jesus is not called adopted because He never became God's Son, but has always been God's Son.

Calling Jesus the only begotten Son of God means that He is of the same nature as God, not a different  nature. To beget is to become the father of: to create is to make. And the difference is this. When you beget, you beget something of the same kind as yourself. A man begets human babies, a beaver begets little beavers...But when you make, you make something of a different kind from yourself. A bird makes a nest, a beaver builds a dam...Now that is the first thing to get clear. What God begets is God; just as what man begets is man. What God creates is not God, just as what man makes is not man.

That is why men are not Sons of God in the same sense that Christ is. They may be like God in certain ways, but they are not things of the same kind. There is a clear distinction between making and begetting--you cannot make what you beget. What you make is different from yourself, what you beget has your nature. Therefore to call Jesus the only begotten Son is to say that He has God's nature and was not made.

Since He has God's nature, He is, by definition, God and therefore eternal. If Jesus was created by God, He could not have been begotten, and John 3:16; John 1:18, 1 John 4:9, etc. are all in error.

Now, you ask about the distinctions between the shared qualities of Jesus Christ and the rest of God's children, so let me put it this way. The Bible identifies God by 1- His names. 2- His titles. 3- His unique attributes. 4- His unique actions. 5- His worship. This means if you were to examine the Bible thoroughly you should be able to quickly discover that there are three and ONLY three "persons" who are identified as God by the COMBINATION of the literary means listed above.

1. CALLED by the NAMES of God (YHWH and its variants) either directly or indirectly, usually both.
2. RECOGNIZED with the TITLES of God (Lord, king, savior, etc.)
3. ATTRIBUTED with the UNIQUE characteristics of God (omnipresence, omnipotence, eternality, etc.)
4. CREDITED with UNIQUE actions of God (creation, origin of God's word, salvation of men etc.
5. WORSHIPPED and/or given the honor, reverence and position due to God ALONE. Please note, I am NOT saying that the Father, Son and Holy Spirit are all consistently, equally and in every mention identified as God in every place they are represented in the Bible by any combination of these 5. Nor am I saying that each person of the trinity is represented equally by ALL FIVE of these means of identifying God.

I AM saying that each person of the trinity receives some COMBINATION of the 5 means of identifying and distinguishing God listed above. A true understanding (within human limits) of who God IS is essential to a valid relationship with Himself according to His own purpose. No valid, systematic theology can be drawn by reducing or eliminating scriptural evidence. We must account for ALL of God's revelation to come to a realization of who God is and what He has done and therefore what His very nature is.

Theology is not salvation. It is in Christ that we find God fully and sufficiently manifested to us human beings, AS a human being and for His own glory. And it is only through His Holy Spirit that we can know Him and be saved by His grace.

Comment: Who the Bible identifies God can be interpreted in countless ways as we see from this babylonian website.  However, my Master identifies God as his Father.  I'm also not sure you understand the question.  Jesus says we are reborn into the family.  That is different than adoption in more ways than are similar.  I'm asking about you to compare Jesus' and the children's' separate progressions to the glory spoken by Jesus in chapter 17 of the gospel of John.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer as well. +1.

Comment: I still have an issue with how you and Dottard are using the word "Christian".  Its used in Acts one time to speak of disciples of Jesus.  If you are conflating the two then you must explain that and you must define the requirements of being a disciple.  That would be make your answers much much stronger.

Comment: @Dottard and also we BECOME children of God.  Meaning there is a progression from receiving (following) and then becoming in John 1:12 by a power given them.  What is this power?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - (1) being a disciple (apprentice or student) of Christ is the same as being a Christian (2) "Christian" occurs in 3 places: Acts 11:26, 26:28, 1 Peter 4:16 (3) while a person become a Christian and disciple at conversion, the process is far from complete - we do not become perfect at conversion but at Jesus return (4) the NT uses Christian, disciple, child of God, spirit-filled, etc as all equivalent names for the converted person. (5) the word "power" is actually better translated, "authority or right"

Comment: @Dottard Your answer doesn't jive with my Master's words. Luke 14:26 If any man come to me, and hate not his father, and mother, and wife, and children, and brethren, and sisters, yea, and his own life also, he cannot be my disciple.

27 And whosoever doth not bear his cross, and come after me, cannot be my disciple....

33 So likewise, whosoever he be of you that forsaketh not all that he hath, he cannot be my disciple.
What are the conditions of being a Christian?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - Christ is simply stating the obvious - many who call themselves "Christian" are nothing of the sort.  Only those dedicated to the service of Christ above all else deserve the title of Christian and disciple.

Comment: @Dottard We can't water down the words of the Son of God who only spoke the words of his God and Father.  He makes it clear in the context, what bearing your cross means.

Comment: @Dottard 37 He that loveth father or mother more than me is not worthy of me: and he that loveth son or daughter more than me is not worthy of me.

38 And he that taketh not his cross, and followeth after me, is not worthy of me.

Comment: I wonder how many real disciples are walking the geocentric earth today?  I think its safe to say.... A Christian by todays "mainstream" standards is NOT a disciple and certainly NOT a child of God.

Comment: @RLPM You said, "Who the Bible identifies God can be interpreted in countless ways as we see from this babylonian website." I  explained to you how God/Jesus Christ is identified as God in 5 ways. If you know other ways besides the 5  mentioned, post them. I would have thought that it is a given that no human meets the standards of those 5 distinctive ways which addresses you question. Have you ever read Philippians 2:5-10 where Jesus who being in the form of God took on the form of a servant/human being? Hence the titles, Son of God and Son of Man. Why are you posting at Babylonian sight?

Comment: I praise the thoughtfulness and structure of your answer.  But Jesus tells us he believes in 1 God and that his 1 God is his Father.  So the 5 ways you mentioned have to be misinterpreted because it goes against Jesus' most important command, the Shema.

Comment: Jesus was not the only begotten son - Psalms 2:7 - "I will declare the decree: the LORD hath said unto me (King David), Thou art my Son; ***this day*** have I begotten thee." ***this day*** is also peculiar for a Begotten son, you would think he would be son from the beginning.  Hebrews 1:5 5 For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou art my Son, ***this day*** have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him a Father, and he shall be to me a Son?

Answer (score 0):

**Similarities**

Christians are similar to Christ in the following ways (a non-exhaustive list):

- Jesus is THE Son of God (Eph 4:13, Matt 26:63, Luke 1:32) that enables us to be children of God, John 1:12, 3:3-8
- Jesus is the light of the world (John 8:12) that enlightens everyone, John 1:4, 5, 9, and so must we be lights to everyone, Matt 5:14-16
- Jesus is the “firstborn” Luke 2:7, Rom 8:29, Col 1:15, 18, Heb 1:6, Rev 1:5, and we are to compose the church/assembly of the firstborn, Heb 12:23; see also Rom 8:23 & Rev 14:4 where we are also called first-fruits to God and the Lamb.
- Jesus is “THE Son of the Most High” (Luke 1:32, Mark 5:7, 8:28) and Christians are called “sons of the Most High” (Luke 6:35).
- Jesus is our sacrifice of atonement and likened to a sacrificial lamb offered for us John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, Eph 5:2, 1 John 2:2, 4:10, Heb 10:10, 12, Rom 3:25, 1 Peter 1:19, etc.  Similarly, the life of a Christian is lived sacrificially for Christ Rom 12:1, Phil 2:17, Heb 13:15.
- Jesus, by His sacrifice on the cross, reconciled sinners to God (Rom 5:10, Col 2:16, 1:20, 22, 2 Cor 5:19), and we must also be involved in the “ministry of reconciliation” (2 Cor 5:18, 19) as “ambassadors for Christ” (2 Cor 5:20).
- Jesus is called the “Lamb of God” (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19) and so are His followers (John 10:1-18, 21:15-17)
- We are co-heirs with Christ of glory.  Rom 8:17.
- We must love as Jesus loved.  John 13:34, 35, 15:12, 1 John 4:8, 11, 19, Eph 5:1, 2
- Jesus was led by the Spirit Matt 4:1. The Christian must be born of the Spirit (John 3:5) by receiving the gift of the Spirit (Acts 2:38) and walk by the Spirit (Gal 5:25, John 6:63, Phil 3:3, John 4:24).  In fact, the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).
- We are being changed into Christ’s glory (= reputation).  2 Cor 3:18
- We are partakers of the divine nature.  2 Peter 1:4
- We are being conformed to the likeness of the Son.  Rom 8:29.
- We are transforming our will and bodies to conform to God’s will.  Rom 12:1, 2.
- Jesus was baptized (Matt 3:13-17, Mark 1:9-11, Luke 3:21, 22) and so should we be baptized, Matt 28:19, Acts 2:38, 10:48, 16:31, 22:16, Rom 6:1-9, etc.
- We are to forgive as Jesus forgave.  Matt 6:12, 14, 15, 18:35, Eph 4:32, Col 3:13.
- We are to have the mind of Christ.  Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16
- Jesus died to sin and was raised to a new life, never to die again.  This is also the process of every sinner in Jesus will also die to sin (at baptism) and be raised to a new eternal life, free of sin.  See Rom 6:8-11.
- Husbands should love their wives as Christ loved His people and gave Himself for her.  Eph 5:25
- Jesus is our great high priest (Heb 4:14, 15, 7:26-28), so too, we are a holy nation of priests.  1 Peter 2:9.
- Jesus is the chief corner-stone and we are also stones in the building. 1 Peter 2:4-6.
- Jesus is the chief shepherd, and elders are to shepherd the flock as He would.  1 Peter 5:1-4.
- We are to be conduits of Jesus’ “water of life”.  John 4:13, 14.
- Jesus is the chief shepherd, and elders are to shepherd the flock as He would.  1 Peter 5:1-4.
- We are to be conduits of Jesus’ “water of life”.  John 4:13, 14.
- Jesus is the promised “seed” (Gen 13:15, 24:7) of Abraham (Gal 3:16) and so are we (Gal 3:29, Rom 9:8).

**Differences**

Christians are very different from Christ in the following ways (a non-exhaustive list):

- Heb 4:15 records that Jesus was tempted in every way just as we are, yet without sin.  We also have Heb 7:26 - *Such a high priest truly befits us—One who is holy, innocent, undefiled, **set apart from sinners**, and exalted above the heavens.*
- The term "monogenes" (= unique one, only begotten") is only applied to Jesus as the unique Son of God (see appendix below) but never to a Christian; this is because Jesus was THE unique Son of God.
- Jesus is called "I Am" in John 4:26, 6:20, 8:24, 28, 58, 13:9, 18:5-8 (see Ex 3:13-15; Deut 32:39, Isa 41:4, 43:10, etc) which Christian are not.
- Jesus is the Savior, Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11 (compare Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21).  Christians are the ones being saved.
- Jesus is the "First and Last" Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13, (compare Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12) which Christians are not
- Jesus is called "Lord of Lords" Rev 17:14, 19:16 (compare Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26) which Christians are not.
- Jesus is called "Lord of All" Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12, Col 1:15 (compare Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13) which Christians are not.
- Jesus is involved with the creation John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2 (compare Isa 44:24, 45:18) which Christians were not.

This is best summarized in two famous NT passages:

- Heb 4:14-16 - Therefore, since we have a great high priest who has passed through the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold firmly to what we profess. For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our weaknesses, but we have one who was tempted in every way that we are, yet was without sin. Let us then approach the throne of grace with confidence, so that we may receive mercy and find grace to help us in our time of need.
- Phil 2:5-11 - Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross. Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

**APPENDIX - Monogenes**

Monogenes is a word of the Greek New Testament that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious. The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD.

- 3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus”, unique.
- once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.
- 5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.

The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.

Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer.  Can you define "Christian"?  Are you referring to the largest religion in the world?   Does that word mean the same thing as it did in the book of Acts?  Instead, I'm specifically speaking of the children of God who John speaks of in his gospel and epistles. John says he gave us power to BECOME the sons of God.  Are you saying everyone who receives him (Christians?), instantaneously and immediately "become sons of God"?  Because that is the only way I can conflate the 2.

Comment: Continued... I'm more specifically asking about the childrens' progress to the same glory as Jesus speaks of in John 17:5.  If my question is not clear, please suggest a way I can edit it.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - John 17:5 does not mention anything about God's children progressing toward the same glory and Jesus as defined there.  So I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - I am using "Christian" in the Biblical sense - the Greek word literally means, "one who is like Christ"; that is, a Christian is a son of God, a follower of Christ, one who is dedicated to the service of Christ, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on Christians in the biblical sense.  What qualifies one as a disciple? and how does that tie in with the children who receive the same glory Jesus received.  John 17:22.

Comment: To increase clarity....do you think I need to edit this question's body and more focus on the glory aspect instead of the first of many aspect?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - if that is your primary focus, then that should be the primary headline question. Indeed, the reference of John 17:22 has only just been added so it cannot have been the primary focus of the original question.  In fact, that is now a quite different question from the original question.  So, another option might be to ask a new question with a new focus.

Comment: Perhaps you are right.  We can see the history of edits.  Its wasn't completely different to begin with.  I was under the impression that we all believed Jesus was speaking of the same glory for him and the children in verse 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139885/discussion-between-read-less-pray-more-and-dottard).